# Hibernate 5: lazy object execute query

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation, hibernate-5.x

In my project I have an entity with this property:

```
/**
 * @return the myObject
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "T1_MYOBJECT")
public MyObject getMyObject()
{
    return myObject;
}
```

When I call method getMyObject() to assign that value to a new object, a query is made on the db to retrieve it. How can I avoid that query? I only want to assign its value to a new object.

Comment: Without loading the object from the database how would Hibernate know its ID and be able to update/create the foreign key correctly at the new object you want to assign it to?

Comment: With a proxy? In that way I get the Id but not the entire object..Am I wrong? How can I get a proxy?